Reference Request for global Hölder continuity of solutions to elliptic PDEs
This is question that was also posted on MathStackExchange Link, where it was suggested I post this question on MathOverflow. Please note that the answer given in Link does not help as I do not have any regularity assumptions on the matrix $A$. Here is my question:
In the article by Littmann, Stampacchia and Weinberger [1], the authors study regularity of boundary points to uniformly elliptic equations of open and bounded subsets of the Euclidean space. More precisely: Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded. Let $A \in L^\infty(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^{n \times n})$ be symmetric and uniformly elliptic, meaning there exists $\lambda > 1$ such that
$$\lambda^{-1} |\xi|^2 \leq \xi \cdot A(x)\xi \leq \lambda |\xi|^2 \quad \text{for all } x \in \Omega.$$
Given a vector field $F: \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, the authors of the article work with the weak formulation of the equation $\operatorname{div}(A \nabla u) = \operatorname{div}(F)$ in $\Omega$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. More precisely, we call $u \in H_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ a solution to the equation $\operatorname{div}(A \nabla u) = \operatorname{div}(F)$ if and only if
$$\int_\Omega \nabla \varphi(x) \cdot A(x) \nabla u(x) \ \mathrm dx = \int_\Omega F (x) \cdot \nabla \varphi(x) \ \mathrm dx\quad \text{for all } \varphi \in H_0^{1,2}(\Omega).$$
As a prerequisite result, they cite the following theorem:
Theorem 2.4: Let $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a ball. Let $p > n$ and let $F \in L^p(B,\mathbb R^n)$. Then the solution $u \in H_0^{1,2}(B)$ of the equation is Hölder continuous in $B$.
As a reference, they cite the articles of Morrey [2] and Stampacchia [3].
My first thought was that they cite the following well known local regularity result of solutions to the PDE, namely:
Interpretation: Let $p > n$ and $F \in L^p(\Omega, \mathbb R^n)$. Let $u \in H_0^{1,2}(B)$ be the solution of $\operatorname{div}(A \nabla u) = \operatorname{div}(F)$. Then there exists $0 < a < 1$ such that: for every $U \subset B$ open and $\overline U \subset B$ there exists $C > 0$ (depending on $\operatorname{dist}(U,\partial B)$) such that
$$\|u\|_{C^{0,a}(U)} \leq C \|F\|.$$
I found plenty of versions of this statement in the literature (e.g. the book of Gilbarg-Trudinger), but later in the paper, they need a global estimate of the following form:
Needed: Let $p > n$ and $F \in L^p(\Omega, \mathbb R^n)$. Let $u \in H_0^{1,2}(B)$ be the solution of $\operatorname{div}(A \nabla u) = \operatorname{div}(F)$. Then there exists $0 < a < 1$ and $C > 0$ such that
$$\|u\|_{C^{0,a}(\overline B)} \leq C \|F\|.$$
The first reference provided (Morrey) only gave an idea of how to prove the statement, the second (Stampacchia) is in Italian and I cannot find a clear statement for the needed Theorem. Researching on my own, I did not find the needed uniform estimate in standard literature, the only reference I came across was the preprint Global Hölder Solvability of second order elliptic equations with locally integrable lower-order coefficients (Hara, 2024).
My question is: Can anyone provide a reference for the Needed Theorem in standard literature?
Thanks in advance.
References
[1] Walter Littman, Hans Weinberger and Guido Stampacchia (1962), "Regular points for elliptic equations with discontinuous coefficients", Annali della Scuola Normale Superiore di Pisa, Classe di Scienze, serie III, Vol. 17, n° 1-2, pp. 43-77, MR161019, Zbl 0116.30302.
[2] Charles B. Morrey, jun., "Second order elliptic equations in several variables and Hölder continuity", Mathematische Zeitschrift 72, 146-164 (1959), MR0120446, Zbl 0094.07802.
[3] Guido Stampacchia, "Problemi al contorno ellittici, con dati discontinui, dotati di soluzioni hölderiane", Annali di Matematica Pura ed Applicata, Serie IV, 51, 1-37 (1960), MR126601, Zbl 0204.42001.

Although not the most accessible ones, Theorem 8.27 and 8.29 of the book of Gilbarg and Trudinger should give what you want.

Thank you very much! That is sufficient for my application.

Such a global Hoelder regularity result requires some minimal assumptions on the geometry of $\Omega$ but no smoothness assumptions on the coefficients.
The classical assumption is a measure density condition: that there exist numbers $0 < \alpha < 1$ and $r_0 > 0$ such that $$\lvert B_r(x) \cap \Omega \rvert \geq \alpha \lvert B_r(x) \rvert \qquad \text{for all}~r < r_0,~x \in \partial\Omega.$$
In the given context, such a property is often called "class $A_\alpha$" or "class $S$" going back to the two classical works that I mention in the next paragraph. Otherwise it is known as a measure density condition, or that $\Omega$ is an "$n$-set" (with $n$ the space dimension). Of course, a convex set such as a ball will satisfy the assumption with $\alpha = 1/2$.
The classical references would be the elliptic Ladyzhenskaya book (Ladyzhenskaya & Ural'tseva: Linear and quasi-linear elliptic equations), which I do not have at hand right now, or Kinderlehrer & Stampacchia: An Introduction to Variational Inequalities and Their Applications. In the latter, Appendix B of Chapter II, Theorem B.4.
These are the classical results for the Dirichlet problem. Of course, in the meantime, many researchers have used these (and other) results to derive associated results on (global) Hoelder regularity for similar boundary value problems by means of localization/transformation techniques under more general but usually also much more complicated geometric assumptions; the literature is quite extensive here.

The monograph by Ladyzhenskaya is impossible for me to penetrate... I feel frustrated that such important and widely cited book has not got re-published with modern typography.

I concur. Luckily, at least in this case, the Kinderlehrer/Stampacchia book offers a much more accessible alternative!

@Akira I completely agree. I once needed a theorem or two from the book and ended up spent over an hour trying to figure out what ancient notations mean...

@Hannes Thank you very much for the extensive answer. I don't have both books at hand right now, but I will check the references.

@Hannes I looked through the book of Ladyzhenskaya & Ural'tseva, but could not find the result. Could you maybe specify where to find it?

@DarkViole7 Yes: Condition (A) is on p.6 in my version, and boundedness+Hoelder regularity of weak solutions to the Dirichlet problem should be in Chapters 3.13/3.14.

@Hannes Thank you very much, I found it now! It is in chapter 13.14 above Remark 1. In my version it is on page 202.
